# Rosmake Build Failed

Tags: ros, build, rosmake, dependencies, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone. Thanks for help.
I'm trying to compile a package in rosjava.
I use cmake . first, without any error, and then rosmake.
Rosmake returns only one error:

[PastebinCode](http://pastebin.com/qvkYFEsL)

The build file is:

[PastebinCode](http://pastebin.com/2ZTmnZ5u)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12731/rosmake-build-failed/) by [Jiraky90](https://answers.ros.org/users/1684/jiraky90/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-01-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's possible you're hitting this issue: http://code.google.com/p/rosjava/issues/detail?id=63

Try: rosmake --threads=1 --pre-clean

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0